# error _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed in tkinter (tk)?

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

So, I was trying to remake "you are an idiot" virus in python. The way I'm doing this is looping my python script. I tried to make it so that when you try to close a window more popups show up.

It was working the 1st time but, then I started getting this error `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed`, and I can't find a way to fix it. Here is my code for how I'm getting this error.

Also another reason why I need it looped is because I'm using `random` functions to make the windows appear in random positions.

```
# On closing function:
def on_closing():
    restart()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.title("you are an idiot")
root.mainloop()

# Restart function:
def restart():
    os.system("python3 main.py")

Random position functions:

#random values
x = random.randint(100,600)
y = random.randint(200,600)
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x,y)) #randomized window position
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could use the event binding for the Destroy event.

```
root.bind("<Destroy>", on_closing)
```

Is the code you shown the main.py?

Comment: that dosent work i get this error _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: you may use another tkinter event.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code block:

```
try:
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", confirm)
except:
    break
```

This code block attempts to set a protocol for the root window to call the `confirm` function when the user tries to close the window. If an error occurs, the `break` statement will exit the loop.

I'd use that exception handling while u want to close your window. Also, you can put your code in while loop and can close your while loop with
exception:
is_goin =False
it gonna help to close your while loop and can check after the parts if u have any calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I discontinued the project long ago now